# SAN for Medium Business - Where to start?

Tags: networking, storage-area-network, network-storage, dell-powervault

I've always run Linux on my home computers, and done PC repair for years, but this is my first experience with needing to buy a SAN. I thought I was knowledgeable, but I feel a bit lost.

I need to be able to support 25 VMs, which are currently managed through vSphere. The company I'm at is growing quickly though, so I'd like to plan for the future. Ideally, I want a solution that I can just tack arrays onto and manage as one large, iSCSI drive.

Suggestions? Good resources? If I can find something that appears to software as one large drive, am I better off going with a solution like FreeNAS or Starwind, or an all-in-one proprietary solution like NetApp?

Cost, is (of course, and always I'm sure) an issue.

Comment: This will get closed as off topic most likely. I suggest you take a look at Drobo on the cheap end, and Equallogic from Dell on the not-so -cheap but featureful end of iSCSI. You'll need a pair or decent gigabit switches to support either solution. You can also roll your own by buying a 2U server with a ton of drives and lighting up FreeNAS like you mentioned. It's very subjective.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!     This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Comment: "Where to start?" -- With a big fat blank cheque.

Comment: Its amusing that two different people mentioned closing the question, one of them a mod, and the question is still open.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek Actually, the question was closed, OT, then re-opened.

Comment: @jscott ah. Is there any way I could have known that? Not being sarcastic or anything, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek Click the [edited X hours ago](http://serverfault.com/posts/403284/revisions) link to see the question's revision history.  I agree, not as intuitive as the "closed" banner.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an overview of what the market has to offer, consider visiting a storage-centered trade fair like the [Storage Networking World](https://www.eiseverywhere.com/ehome/index.php?eventid=39872&). Your questions can be addressed there by the vendor's engineers.

Presenting as a "one large iSCSI drive" is one of the most basic features every solution will offer, but you might want to look at other differentiating factors like

- performance (especially under random virtualization load)
- tiered storage (a performance optimization really)
- advanced features like snapshots, mirroring, thin provisioning, compression, encryption or deduplication
- redundancy features (like using 2 independent controllers or redundant power supplies)
- ability to control attached enclosures to accomodate for growth
- management tools and available statistics / graphs
- support plans and warranty (you would *really* want your storage to be repaired quickly in the case of a defect if it is the single point of failure for all your virtual machines)

Good hunting.